# Is it possible to take a SQLParameter object and have it spit out a sql variable declaration in the c# layer?

Tags: c#, debugging, sqlparameter

*Note: This is just for debugging assistance, this isn't going to go into production, I'm just finding I have a slow workflow and I'd like to if possible speed it up*

I am doing some debugging in a .net application that uses some table valued sql parameters. I want to generate SQL code from the c# layer to throw into SSMS for debugging purposes. It should be noted, I do not want the exact text of the EF-Generated SQL query, but rather I want sql that will define and populate corrosponding sql variables for my sqlparameter objects.

Right now I just have a "generate sql" function that does a lot of string concatenation, but every time I refactor a sql table type or add a new argument I have to update that string function -- it's not very robust and keeping it in sync with my refactors is slowing me down considerably.

I'd rather just pass a list of sqlParameter objects and get a string back that has all the declarations and variable setting. Is there a native way to take a SQL parameter variable and get back something like

```
DECLARE @SomeVar SQLTableType
INSERT INTO @SomeVar VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
INSERT INTO @SomeVar VALUES ('baz', 'buz')
```

or in the case of a scalar variable

```
DECLARE @SomeOtherVar varchar(100)
set @SomeOtherVar = 'ThisIsAValue'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is _No_.  If you are using EF, you can get the SQL associated with the query _after_ you materialize the query.  Otherwise, you are the person writing the SQL (if you are using raw ADO.NET or Dapper).  Other than EF, I don't know of any way to get SQL code out of C#.

Comment: Such code is not particularly hard to write, but there is nothing in the framework to do it. The reason, incidentally, is not that mean implementers chose to withhold a private implementation from you, but because it truly isn't needed: on the protocol level, parameters are not transmitted as text but as a sequence of bytes that encode things like the type, precision, scale, nullability and of course the actual value. Code to spit out a textual representation would just be stuff that has to be maintained on the side for no great benefit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `Code to spit out a textual representation would just be stuff that has to be maintained on the side for no great benefit` So what you're sayiing is that maintainers don't want to build it for the exact same reason I want it built? :) It is nice to know that the sql is never actually generated though.